# Для не статического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект. В чем проблема? Ошибка на каждой примененной функции в Main

Tags: c#, классы

Для не статического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект. В чем проблема? Ошибка на каждой примененной функции в `Main`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace PacMan
{
    public class Character
    {
        public char name;
        public int x;
        public int y;

    }

    class Program
    {
        public Character hero;
        public Character enemy1;
        public Character enemy2;

        public void InitialisationCharacters()
        {
            hero = new Character();
            hero.name = '@';
            hero.x = 22;
            hero.y = 5;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitialisationCharacters();//Ошибка
            char[,] map;
            map = MapData("maps//map1.txt");//Ошибка
            DrawMap(map);//Ошибка
            ConsoleKey s = Console.ReadKey().Key;
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            map[hero.x, hero.y] = hero.name;//Ошибка
            DrawMap(map);//Ошибка
        }


        public char[,] MapData(string path)
        {
            string[] str;
            str=File.ReadAllLines(path);
            char[,] map = new char[str.Length,str[0].Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < str[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    map[i, j] = str[i][j];
                }
            }
            return map;

        }

        public void DrawMap(char[,] map)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1);j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(map[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в классе Program все методы должны быть статическими

Comment: @AntonNikolaev, не должны

Comment: @Grundy чтобы ошибка пропала, я имел ввиду

Comment: @AntonNikolaev, сейчас выглядит, как будто они всегда такими должны быть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static void Main(string[] args)` статический метод, а это значит, что он может обращаться только к статическим членам класса (полям, методам), которыми
`InitialisationCharacters, MapData, DrawMap` и др. не являются.

Comment: а почему Main должен быть статик? почему нельзя создать void Main(string[] args)?

Comment: @SomeTimeDead, потому что это точка входа в программу (выполнение начинается именно с него), которая выполняется **без создания экземпляра класса**

Comment: @SomeTimeDead, ты можешь создать `void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: @Grundy компилятор не разрешает.

Comment: @SomeTimeDead, разрешает. Все зависит от типа проекта или наличия другой точки входа

Comment: Внутри Main можно создать экземпляр класса Program и вызывать его методы.